# How can I identify gauge transformations of fields with gauge transformations on a principal bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory

I have some trouble with identifying what we do in physics regarding fields and bundle theory.

I start from the following construction which I hope is ok: with a Lie group G and a smooth manifold M I can construct a locally trivial principal bundle. If M is Minkowski which can be covered by a single chart, the bundle is trivial, so the total space is $P=M\times G$. 
 I choose a representation of G on a carrier space V and I construct an associated bundle with fibre V. It will have the same base space M and the total space $P_V=P\times V/\sim$ where the equivalence relation is the usual one for associated bundles. (the left action of G on V is given by the representation) Fields are then sections in this associated bundle.

My problem is related to (local) gauge transformations. As far that I know, they are maps $S:M\rightarrow G$ which are in one-to-one correspondence with automorphisms on $P$. On the principal bundle I can choose a connection and then a smooth section in order to pullback the connection to the base space. I can make a gauge transformation to change my section and look at the new components of the connection on base space.

1. I don't know how is this related to fields which are on the associated bundle. How are they affected by the gauge transformation? In physics we make the gauge transformation on the fields and then require invariance of the Langrangian density, thus introducing the covariant derivative.
2. How can I translate this invariance in bundle language? It is something we require or is it intrinsic in the construction?

edit: it's ok, I found the answer. I used the theorem which relates the sections on the associated bundle with equivariant maps $:P\rightarrow V$. A section $\psi$ viewed this way will go into another section $\psi'=\psi\circ\varphi$ at the automorphism $\varphi:P\rightarrow P$. We known these automorphisms are in 1-to-1 relation with the gauge transformations because the principal bundle is trivial. The equivariance condition for $\psi$ gives exactly the result. It is then trivial to pass back from these maps $:P\rightarrow V$ to sections and see they change with $\rho(g^{-1}(x))$ where $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is the representation.

So indeed if we start with a section (thus also a Yang-Mills field) on the principal bundle and with a section on the associated bundle, at a gauge transformation $\Omega:M\rightarrow G$ the section on the associated bundle will also change with $\rho(\Omega^{-1})$. In this sense, we can "make the gauge transformation" on fields.

I also have an intuition about the gauge invariance stuff, related to the space of physical configurations which is set of Yang-Mills fields modulo gauge transformations.

I thought it may be useful to write this here in case someone else has the same question.